# Incompatible pointer types returning **'from a function with result type '*'

Tags: objective-c, ios

Basically, I have a base class called BaseObject.  2nd type of classes called RedObject, BlueObject. that are subclasses of BaseObject class.

So, in the RedObject.h, it has:

```
#import "BaseObject.h"

@interface RedObject : BaseObject
```

And in the BlueObject.h, it has:

```
#import "BaseObject.h"

@interface BlueObject : BaseObject
```

I also have a third type of class called MyObject.  In the MyObject.h file, it has:

```
#import "RedObject.h"
#import "BlueObject.h"

@interface MyObject : NSObject

-(id)init:(char)objectType;
```

In the MyObject.m file, it has:

```
-(id)init:(char)objectType
{
    self = [super init];
    switch (objectType) 
    {
        case 'R':
        {
            return [[RedObject alloc]init];  // this is where the yellow warning message 1
        }
        case 'B':
        {
            BlueObject *blueObject = [[BlueObject alloc]init];
            return blueObject;          // this is where the yellow warning message 2
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Waring message 1: Incompatible pointer types returning *RedObject*'from a function with result type 'MyObject*'

Waring message 2: Incompatible pointer types returning *BlueObject*_strong'from a function with result type 'MyObject*'

When I tried to instantiate an instance of MyObject from a caller class, it works fine.  I can verify that I have accessed to all properties of the RedObject/BlueObject and the BaseObject.  But not sure how to remedy the yellow warning.  Or if I missed something?

```
MyObject *myObject = [[MyObject alloc]init:'R'];  // or 'B'
```

Comment: What does `BaseObject` descend from?

Comment: BaseObject is subclass of NSObject.

Comment: Either way, this isn't a good way to initialize subclasses. Typically `init` is expected to return the same object that was alloc'd. You should consider a factory pattern here instead.

Comment: Anyway,that's strange... It shouldn't complain when you return `id`...

Comment: Also, make sure to include `if (self){` in your init method.

Comment: My guess is that the conventions the compiler follows expect a function starting with init to return an object of either that type, or a subtype, despite the fact that it is marked as `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not have a class method that does all the construction.

```
+(id)newObject:(char)objectType
{
    switch (objectType) 
    {
        case 'R':
            return [[RedObject alloc]init]; //self;

        case 'B':
            BlueObject *object = [[BlueObject alloc]init];
            return object;

        default:
            return [[MyObject alloc]init];
    }
}
```

This would be used as follows

```
MyObject *myObject = [MyObject newObject:'H'];
```

Comment: I ended up using the class method.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments posted and especially from @kevboh, I made some modification as follow and it seemed to solve my problem.

In MyObject.h:

```
//-(id)init:(char)objectType;  //removed

-(id)getObject:(char)objectType;  //added
```

In MyObject.m:

//remove the -(id)init:(char)objectType method

// added this method

```
-(id)getObject:(char)objectType
    {
        switch (objectType) 
        {
            case 'R':
            {
                return [[RedObject alloc]init]; //self;
            }
            case 'B':
            {
                BlueObject *object = [[BlueObject alloc]init];
                return object;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
        return nil;
    }
```

And in the caller class, use this:

```
MyObject *myObject = [[[MyObject alloc]init] getObject:'H'];
```

Comment: However, it creates a few new ones.  1) The object that's returned is really a BaseObject in spite of you assigning it to a `MyObject *` and, 2) the `MyObject` that you allocated in order to call `getObject` is a leak (unless you are using ARC and then it's just odd).

Comment: Additionally: 1) Don't use `get` at the beginning of a method name in most cases (there are certain cases where it's the norm, but when just retrieving a value it isn't). 2) This looks like it should be a class method; specifically a factory. 3) The method name should have something before the colon that indicates what the next parameter signifies, e.g. `+(id)objectWithType:(char)objectType`. 4) Your `switch` syntax is incorrect, although it compiles.

Comment: @PhillipMills:  Yeah!  I thought about that afterward.  So, I replaced it with a class method that is similar to Jeffrey Thomas's answer.  So if nobody posts any other solution, I will select his answer as the answer to this question.

Comment: @echristopherson:  Good suggestion and class method it is.  See my comment above.