# Incompatible pointer types returning 'FIRCLSURLSessionConfiguration *' from a function with result type 'NSURLSessionConfiguration *'

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, firebase

With XCode 12.5 and Firebase Pods, I am getting two times this warning in the FirebaseCrashlytics code. There is a similar question already ([Incompatible pointer types returning **'from a function with result type '*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622949/incompatible-pointer-types-returning-from-a-function-with-result-type)), however, I don't know how to solve the problem in my case.

The code with the warning is here:

```
#import "FIRCLSURLSessionAvailability.h"

#import "FIRCLSURLSession.h"

#if FIRCLSURLSESSION_REQUIRED
#import "FIRCLSURLSessionConfiguration.h"

@implementation FIRCLSURLSessionConfiguration

@synthesize URLCache = _URLCache;
@synthesize HTTPAdditionalHeaders = _additionalHeaders;
@synthesize HTTPCookieAcceptPolicy = _cookiePolicy;

+ (NSURLSessionConfiguration *)defaultSessionConfiguration {
  if ([FIRCLSURLSession NSURLSessionShouldBeUsed]) {
    return [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
  }

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
  return [self new]; // Warning here: Incompatible pointer types returning 'FIRCLSURLSessionConfiguration *' from a function with result type 'NSURLSessionConfiguration *'
#else
  return [[self new] autorelease];
#endif
}

+ (NSURLSessionConfiguration *)ephemeralSessionConfiguration {
  if ([FIRCLSURLSession NSURLSessionShouldBeUsed]) {
    return [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
  }

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
  return [self new]; // Warning here: Incompatible pointer types returning 'FIRCLSURLSessionConfiguration *' from a function with result type 'NSURLSessionConfiguration *'
#else
  return [[self new] autorelease];
#endif
}

+ (NSURLSessionConfiguration *)backgroundSessionConfiguration:(NSString *)identifier {
  return [self backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:identifier];
}
```

There is also one of the gray XCode hints: 1. Class method 'new' is assumed to return an instance of its receiver type ('FIRCLSURLSessionConfiguration *')

at this code in an other file:

```
+ (instancetype)new OBJC_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("use object initializers instead");
```

Comment: What version of Crashlytics?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to silence this error so far is to add a line on the top of my `Podfile`

`inhibit_all_warnings!`

Then I do a `pod install` and I'm not getting that error anymore.  This is definitely a band-aid, and it should probably be fixed by updating the offending Pod.